# Making multiple selections in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, selection

Is there any way to make multiple selections in tkinter?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "consolas 14")
text.pack()

text.insert('1.0' , "This is the first line.\nThis is the second line.\nThis is the third line.")

mainloop()
```

Here, I want be able to select multiple text from where ever I want.

Here is an Image(GIF) that explains what I mean:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this in tkinter?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: You could possibly use `text.tag_add(SEL, index)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a short demo, with `Control` key hold you could select multiple text. Check this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class SelectableText(tk.Text):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwarg):
        super().__init__(master, **kwarg)
        self.down_ind = ''
        self.up_ind = ''
        self.bind("<Control-Button-1>", self.mouse_down)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.mouse_drag)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.mouse_up)
        self.bind("<BackSpace>", self.delete_)

    def mouse_down(self, event):
        self.down_ind = self.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y}")

    def mouse_drag(self, event):
        self.up_ind = self.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y}")
        if self.down_ind and self.down_ind != self.up_ind:
            self.tag_add(tk.SEL, self.down_ind, self.up_ind)
            self.tag_add(tk.SEL, self.up_ind, self.down_ind)

    def mouse_up(self, event):
        self.down_ind = ''
        self.up_ind = ''

    def delete_(self, event):
        selected = self.tag_ranges(tk.SEL)
        if len(selected) > 2:
            not_deleting = ''
            for i in range(1, len(selected) - 1):
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    not_deleting += self.get(selected[i-1].string, selected[i].string)
            self.delete(selected[0].string, selected[-1].string)
            self.insert(selected[0].string, not_deleting)
            return "break"


root = tk.Tk()

text = SelectableText(root, width=50, height=10)
text.grid()
text.insert('end', "This is the first line.\nThis is the second line.\nThis is the third line.")

root.mainloop()
```

So I was trying to delete each selection with the `Text.delete(index1, index2)` but when the first selection in one line is deleted, the indices changes, making the subsequent `delete` deleting indices not selected (or out of range in the particular line.

I had to work around another way - first deleting from the first selected to the last selected, just like what `BackSpace` would do by default, then put back every unselected part in the middle. The `Text.tag_ranges` gives you a list of ranges selected in this way:

```
[start1, end1, start2, end2, ...]
```

where each entry is a `<textindex object>` with a `string` property (the index). So you can extract the text between `end1` and `start2`, between `end2` and `start3`, etc. to the end, and store these into a variable (`not_deleting`) so you can insert them back into the text.

There should be better and neater solutions but for now this is what it is... Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. This works just like I expected, but when I try to delete the selected text, it deletes the text that is not selected as well. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @Lenovo360 I added a delete function to it. Now it should work with delete. but if you want to do other things like copy, you need to define another function to override the default one.

Comment: @quioxuan zhang: The text widget does not delete all the selected items. When I make 5 selections and press the `BackSpace` key, only 3 selections get deleted. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @Lenovo360 should be good now. I changed the logic a little bit.

Comment: Thank you, It works now, but can you please edit your answer and explain what is actually happening in the `delete()` function? I am asking this because it will be better if I have a good understanding of what is going on in the code.

Comment: @Lenovo360 I tried to explain a little about it. Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @qiaoxuan zhang. Your explanation made the concepts much more clear to me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For the `delete_` method proposed by Qiaoxuan Zhang, I advise to use the `Text.tag_nextrange` method in a loop like this :

```
def delete_sel(self):        
while 1:
    result = self.tag_nextrange(tk.SEL, 1.0)           
    if result :
        self.delete(result[0] , result[1])
    else :
        break
```

For those who would like to add the missing features:

- correction of selection when changing direction of sliding
- take into account the double-click

Take a look here : [French site](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d2116900/autres-langages/python/gui/tkinter/widget-text-tkinter-selection-multiple-texte-possible-maniere-manuelle/)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: set the `exportselection` attribute of each Text widget to `False`

Tkinter gives you control over this behaviour with the `exportselection` configuration option for the Text widget as well as the Entry and Listbox widgets. Setting it to `False` prevents the export of the selection to the X selection, allowing the widget to retain its selection when a different widget gets focus.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
...
text1 = tk.Text(..., exportselection=False)
text2 = tk.Text(..., exportselection=False)
```

you can find more info here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/options.htm#M-exportselection